# Why is the import failing while implementing OpenVino on Colab notebook?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, openvino

import cv2
import numpy as np
from utils.opv import OpvModel,OpvExec

Import Error: cannot import name 'IEPlugin' from 'openvino.inference_engine' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/openvino/inference_engine/**init**.py)

The error is associated with **int**.py and opv.py files used

Answer (score 1):

IEPlugin class has been deprecated since OpenVINO 2021.1 release. Use [IECore](https://docs.openvino.ai/2021.4/api/ie_python_api/_autosummary/openvino.inference_engine.IECore.html) instead.